# How to build aggregated Allure report from launches in several Jenkins instances?

Tags: jenkins, reporting, allure

We have several Jenkins and several repositories with cucumber and selenium tests. Is there a way to build aggregated Allure report for launches in several Jenkins instances?

Comment: There is no such feature available out of the box.

Comment: In general is it possible with Allure+Cucumber? Somehow...?

Comment: In general you need to create service that will accept all the results and generate aggregated report. Our team are working on such service (you can contact me on Gitter for more details https://gitter.im/baev ) or use other solutions such as Report Portal instead of Allure